# Is there a way to feed jwplayer the segments of a video manually?

Tags: javascript, plugins, jwplayer

To make it short, I'm writing a plugin to get the segments from a hls playlist from my own server (using websocket) rather than the CDN.

I managed to replace the xhr but I've now been stuck trying to pass the segment to the jwplayer. I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own provider to request and render media - https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks.